# I need to remove a question with sensitive data

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109/cryptanalysis-reverse-engineer-what-should-be-an-easy-hash

I have been notified that I cannot post this information anywhere online and I need this question to be taken down. I have edited the specific information out of it, but the revisions would hold the information.

Comment: What *is* the sensitive data? I mean, there never was any useful information on the hash function in the question. The question should be simply closed IMO, for it is not a good question.

Comment: The numbers that were being hashed were Student IDs.

Comment: See also [this meta.so question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57925). Moderators can't super-delete things, but it seems like the StackExchange team may be able to. I recommend you email them directly at team@stackexchange.com.

Comment: Are all "criptography" tagged questions and/or answers sensitive?

I am afraid of that!

Answer (score 2):

I flagged the question and it should be deleted shortly.

Comment: you should delete this question from meta to avoid drawing attention to your sensitive data.

Comment: I would except that the original question is deleted. I'll leave this one up so people can realize that they can flag it for deletion.

Comment: FYI, 2k+ rep users can see deleted questions. I don't know if there is a more complete way to remove the data.

Comment: @Akhil: Not for regular users or mods. See my comment on the question.